# Uninitialized exception while initializing "late init" property

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I am not really sure if my case is just not possible with late init properties. But let me just ask :)

I have an applicationController which is used in nearly every activity - so i created a [BaseActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSNo7.png)

The problem now is that when I want to get dependencies from the application controller in the [child activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOwr4.png),  I get an [Uninitialized Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrUnh.png).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try using `this` instead of `applicationContext`

Comment: Are you calling super in the onCreate methods of children activities?

Comment: Try declaring the property like this and removing the initialisation from your onCreate: val applicationController by lazy { ApplicationController.getInstance(this)}

Comment: Why would you take screenshots of your IDE and posting images of _code_ here? Please use the code formatter and copy-paste it.

Comment: thanks for the info shkschneider - will do it next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you override wrong method in `BaseActivity`, that why your app crash.

**Solution:** Change your code to

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var applicationController: ApplicationController

    // [IMPORTANT] Remove or comment-out this method
//    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
//        applicationController = ApplicationController.getInstance(applicationContext)
//    }

    // Override this method
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        applicationController = ApplicationController.getInstance(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** This section will explain why the code is not working.

> **kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException**
>
> This is a sub-class of RuntimeException, the app will throw this
>   exception when you access an object by calling properties or methods
>   on its own before initializing.

When `LoginScreen` activity is created, Android will call its `onCreate` method.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen)

    emailMatcher = applicationController.getEmailMatcher()
    passwordMatcher = applicationController.getPasswordMatcher()
}
```

The first line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` will call `onCreate` method of its parent, in this case `onCreate (bundle)` in `BaseActivity` activity will be called.

Unfortunately, in `BaseActivity` activity, you override and put the initial code for `applicationController` in another method `onCreate(bundle, persistentState)` which quite similar to `onCreate (bundle)`. The difference between them is number of params. As a result, at this time `applicationController` is still not initialized.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
    applicationController = ApplicationController.getInstance(applicationContext)
}
```

Until the app reach this line

```
emailMatcher = applicationController.getEmailMatcher()
```

Because you call `getEmailMatcher` method on an uninitialized object `applicationController`, so the app throws `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException` and make your app crash.

Comment: Thank you very much - it does work now :)
Can you explain a bit further why this is happening?

Comment: @thovor Please see the `explanation` section in my answer.